# Extracting frames from HLS stream in python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, computer-vision

I have a HLS stream and wanted to extract frame as it appears for computer vision using opencv in python. I have tried exploring ffmpeg but it seems to read .mp4 easily but not the hls stream (m3u8). Is there any other option or other API of ffmpeg-python to extract frame from HLS stream.

Here is the sample code which I thought of giving a try but is not working with VIDEO_URL

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import ffmpeg
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp

VIDEO_URL = "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"
VIDEO_FILE = "sampleStream.mp4"

process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(VIDEO_FILE)
    #.input(VIDEO_URL)
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)

tar = 200
val = 0

while True:
    val = val + 1
    in_bytes = process1.stdout.read(100 * 200 * 3)
    if not in_bytes:
        print('Breaking - No bytes found.')
        break
    in_frame = (
        np
        .frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8)
        .reshape([100, 200, 3])
    )
    if val == tar:
        print('Writing image...')
        cv2.imwrite("sample.jpg", in_frame)
        break
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? "Not working" does not get enough information to diagnose anything.

Comment: The code get stuck while reading from the output stream, when using video_url as the parameter. I do not think this is the right way to use this API, but searched over internet and have not seen another example so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cv2.VideoCapture()` to read the HLS stream directly. Why suffer?

```
import cv2
import sys

VIDEO_URL = "http://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_URL)
if (cap.isOpened() == False):
    print('!!! Unable to open URL')
    sys.exit(-1)

# retrieve FPS and calculate how long to wait between each frame to be display
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
wait_ms = int(1000/fps)
print('FPS:', fps)

while(True):
    # read one frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # TODO: perform frame processing here

    # display frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(wait_ms) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I tried this approach as well which was giving me the following error: 

tls @ 0x7f93a9f1ff40] Error decoding the received TLS packet.
[hls @ 0x7f93a500ec00] Error when loading first segment 'https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/video/6000kbit/seq-0.ts'
OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"
!!! Unable to open URL

Comment: Update to a more recent OpenCV! I'm using **4.2.0** on Windows.

Comment: I am using 4.2.0 but on mac. Seems like permission issue.

Comment: Glad it helped you! Feel free to up vote the answers that helped you solve the problem and click on the checkbox near an answer to select it as the official problem solver. By doing these things you will be helping future visitors find their answers more quickly.

Comment: It doesn't work, the fps returns 48, but I think the correct fps can be gotten by the tbr using ffmpeg as following `ffmpeg -i "http://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"` which returns 24

Comment: My code is fine. However, the correct FPS value returned from `cap.get()` depends on the OpenCV version you are using and also the underlaying Operating System. Which means this code can work perfectly on some computers and fail on other setups.

Answer (score 0):

@karlphillip solution works but it's important to note that you first need to install a build of cv2 that includes ffmpeg.

You can check if ffmpeg is setup correctly for cv2 by putting the following in your code:

```
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

It should say "YES" after ffmpeg.

#### Installation for Conda users (uninstall opencv first if it was already installed):

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

#### Installation for None Conda users:

Apparently it's a bit of a process to install cv2 with ffmpeg manually so I opted to use a docker image. I found this one and it works well https://github.com/Borda/docker_python-opencv-ffmpeg

My Dockerfile extends the above base image like this:

```
FROM borda/docker_python-opencv-ffmpeg:cpu-py3.7-cv4.5.1

# More docker file stuff...
```